# php order array multiple times, but keep previous orderings

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

So I need to make a list of team results, but I need to sort them. I can't do that is SQL (since the data needs to be calculated every time). What I currently tried to do to sort the data is the following:

```
usort($result, function($a, $b)
{
    return $a['out_of_time'] - $b['out_of_time'] && $a['tot_controls'] < $b['tot_controls'] && $a['tot_gtks'] < $b['tot_gtks'] && $a['distance'] < $b['distance'];
});
```

but that doesn't work out at all... the data I have is the following:

```
[
    {
        "team_number": 101,
        "pilot": "Robin Tralala",
        "navigator": "Another Person",
        "distance": 0,
        "points_per_gtk": {
            "gtk_1": 2,
            "gtk_2": 2
        },
        "tot_gtks": 4,
        "tot_timecontrols": 2,
        "tot_controls": 20,
        "tot_points": 22,
        "out_of_time": false
    },
    {
        "team_number": 102,
        "pilot": "Bertje Bibber",
        "navigator": "Derp Kwakkel",
        "distance": 0,
        "points_per_gtk": {
            "gtk_1": 4,
            "gtk_2": 1
        },
        "tot_gtks": 5,
        "tot_timecontrols": 1,
        "tot_controls": 0,
        "tot_points": 1,
        "out_of_time": false
    }
]
```

Well, I need to sort on the `tot_controls` then on the `points_per_gtk` values and then on the `distance`. How could I do this in PHP?

**EDIT**

I have written some more code, and got to this point;

```
usort($result, function($a, $b)
{
    $strafpunten = (int)$a['tot_timecontrols'] <=> (int)$b['tot_timecontrols'];

    foreach($a['points_per_gtk'] as $gtk_name => $points)
    {
        $gtk_points = (int)$a['points_per_gtk'][$gtk_name] <=> (int)$b['points_per_gtk'][$gtk_name];

        if($gtk_points)
        {
            return $gtk_points;
        }
    }

    if($strafpunten)
    {
        return $strafpunten;
    }

    return (int)$a['distance'] <=> (int)$b['distance'];
});
```

I just really don't know if this sorts correctly...

Comment: so you need an array of 3 levels, right?

Comment: Yes, based on my Json response, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not so long ago, I wrote [a php library for that exact purpose](https://github.com/Stratadox/Sorting).

You can use it like this:

```
<?php
use Stratadox\Sorting\ArraySorter;
use Stratadox\Sorting\Sort;

$table = [
    ['name' => 'Bar', 'rating' => 1],
    ['name' => 'Foo', 'rating' => 3],
    ['name' => 'Baz', 'rating' => 1],
];
$sorter = new ArraySorter();
$table = $sorter->sortThe($table, 
    Sort::descendingBy('rating', Sort::descendingBy('name'))
);

assert($table == [
    ['name' => 'Foo', 'rating' => 3],
    ['name' => 'Baz', 'rating' => 1],
    ['name' => 'Bar', 'rating' => 1],
]);
```

In your case, that would be:

```
$sorted = (new ArraySorter())->sortThe($result, 
    Sort::descendingBy('out_of_time', 
        Sort::descendingBy('tot_controls', 
            Sort::descendingBy('tot_gtks', 
                Sort::descendingBy('distance')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Change `descending` into `ascending` wherever needed.

You can simply install the library by using `composer require stratadox/sorting`.

**Edit**: Based on the comments below this answer, it appears multi-dimensional array support is needed. This can be achieved by instead using the `NestedArraySorter`:

```
$sorted = (new NestedArraySorter())->sortThe($result, 
    Sort::descendingBy('part_one.total', 
        Sort::descendingBy('part_one.gtk', 
            Sort::descendingBy('part_one.distance')
        )
    )
);
```

Beware that when using the `NestedArraySorter`, the ability to reach array offsets that contain dots is lost.

Comment: Could it maybe made to a laravel package?

Comment: Because I installed it, but I can't use it, it says `class ArraySorter not found`

Comment: Hi! The package already works with Laravel, however you need to put `use Stratadox\Sorting\ArraySorter;` and `use Stratadox\Sorting\Sort;` at the top of the file! I'll update the answer a bit.

Comment: For a "real life" example of how to use it, you can also take a look at [the tests](https://github.com/Stratadox/Sorting/blob/master/tests/Integration/Sorting_arrays_of_arrays.php) :)

Comment: How would you sort multi-dimentional arrays using your code? Since I have for example this: https://gist.github.com/RosiersRobin/5c0aed9361f7f0d9e0d853d7604f0033

Comment: Nice, an unsupported use case! I've added support for it in v0.1.1, by adding a `NestedArraySorter` class. You can use it in place of `ArraySorter`, and use dot-notation to split the array keys. (It's no BC break: just run `composer update` to get it)